# Why I can't reimplement methode from QIODevice when base class is QFile?

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, qfile, qiodevice

when my base class is QIODevice I can reimplement writeData and readData, but if the base class is QFile it doesn't work. The base class of OFile is QFileDevice and the base class of QFileDevice is QIODevice:

```
//This works:
//class xyseriesiodevice : public QIODevice

//This doesn't work
class xyseriesiodevice : public QFile
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit xyseriesiodevice(QXYSeries * series, QObject *parent = 0);

protected:
    qint64 readData(char * data, qint64 maxSize);
    qint64 writeData(const char * data, qint64 maxSize);
```

When calling

```
//m_device is of type xyseriesiodevice
//m_audioInput is of type QAudioInput    
m_device->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
m_audioInput->start(m_device);
```

`writeData` from `xyseriesiodevice` is only called when the base class is`QIODevice`

Thanks!!

Comment: It should work. Have you checked the result of the `open()` call? If the open fails then probably QAudioOutput won't call `writeData()`.

Comment: FWIW I tried modifying the QT example program (at `qtmultimedia/examples/multimedia/audioinput`) so that its `AudioInfo` class subclass QFile rather than QIODevice, and after doing that (and after changing the AudioInfo::start() method to call open(stdout, QIODevice::WriteOnly)), I can see that AudioInfo::writeData() is being called at regular intervals with 4096-byte chunks of audio data.  This is under MacOS/X with Qt 5.10.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't include QFile library try including it.
Try also adding "override" keyword after method signature.

```
qint64 readData(char * data, qint64 maxSize) override;
qint64 writeData(const char * data, qint64 maxSize) override;
```

Comment: The code will fail to compile if `QFile` is not declared - that's some cargo cult recommendation. The `override` is the correct recommendation.